# The nature of lists in python, why do I get a repeating list?

Tags: python

So, I was writing a program for an assignment on Coursera, I solved it but I got some unintended behavior.
The following code with the input of romeo.txt:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname, 'r')
lst = list()
words = ''
fin = list()
for line in fh:
    words += line.strip(' ')

words = words.replace('\n', ' ')

for line in words:
    lst += words.split(' ')
print(lst)
```

Instead of giving me a list of words only appearing once, it gives me every word, but repeated an unknown number of times.

```
Gives me a huge list
of repeating words: ['But', 'soft', 'what', 'light', 'through', 'yonder', 'window', 'breaks', 'It', 'is', 'the', 'east', 'and', 'Juliet', 'is', 'the', 'sun', 'Arise', 'fair', 'sun', 'and', 'kill', 'the', 'envious', 'moon', 'Who', 'is', 'already', 'sick', 'and', 'pale', 'with', 'grief', 'But', 'soft', 'what', 'light', 'through', 'yonder', 'window', 'breaks', 'It', 'is', 'the', 'east', 'and', 'Juliet', 'is', 'the', 'sun', 'Arise', 'fair', 'sun', 'and', 'kill', 'the', 'envious', 'moon', 'Who', 'is', 'already', 'sick', 'and', 'pale', 'with', 'grief', 'But', 'soft', 'what', 'light', 'through', 'yonder', 'window', 'breaks', 'It', 'is', 'the', 'east', 'and', 'Juliet', 'is', 'the', 'sun', 'Arise', 'fair', 'sun', 'and', 'kill', 'the', 'envious', 'moon', 'Who', 'is', 'already', 'sick', 'and', 'pale', 'with', 'grief', 'But', 'soft', 'what', 'light', 'through', 'yonder', 'window', 'breaks', 'It', 'is', 'the', 'east', 'and', 'Juliet', 'is', 'the', 'sun', 'Arise', 'fair', 'sun' . . . .,
```

The words repeat SO much more than that.

Comment: `for line in words: lst += line.split(' ')` ? you definately don't want to be appending `words` here

Comment: Are you saying that the resulting list is not in the same order left to right as the words in romeo.txt?

Comment: @chris_rands but why not?

Answer (score 2):

Initially you said:

```
words = ''
```

Ok. So `words` is a string.
Then, you said:

```
for line in fh:
    words += line.strip(' ')
```

For every line in the file, strip spaces from the current line and append it to `words`. Each iteration you are appending to your `words` string. When the loop is done, `words` will be one giant string.

Then, you said:

```
words = words.replace('\n', ' ')
```

Ok. `words` is still a string. All you've done is replace all newline characters with spaces.

Then, you said:

```
for line in words:
    lst += words.split(' ')
```

`line` in this case, is not a good name for this temporary variable, since you are not iterating over the lines anymore. Your iterable is `words`, which is a string. When you iterate over a string, you get individual characters, not lines:

```
>>> for line in "abcdefg":
    print(line)


a
b
c
d
e
f
g
>>>
```

Just because I'm calling the temporary variable `line`, doesn't mean that that's what it actually is. I could have called it anything and I still would have received the same output. A better name for this variable, therefore, would be `char`, for example.

Back to your snippet, since you are iterating over the characters in your `words` string, you are extending your `list` with the result of `words.split(' ')`, once for every character! I don't need to see your input file to know that that's a gigantic list. The number of strings in your `lst` list will be approximately equal to the number of words in the file multiplied by the number of characters in the file.

Comment: We spotted the real problem at the same time but you were 1. faster and 2. your explanation is way better than mine... +1  (but i suggest that you add a recipe for using a `set` to perform the task)

Comment: @gboffi, Thank you! I realize that when the OP says "Instead of giving me a list of words only appearing once", it does sound like they want a set. However, I'm not convinced that this is how the OP's phrasing is meant to be interpreted. We don't know what their Coursera assignment was asking for (at least I don't), and I can't glean any attempt by the OP to retain only unique words just by looking at their code. Perhaps what they meant was, in the context of an absurdly long list, they were expecting the list of all words printed once (OP: If my assumption is wrong look at gboffi's answer).

Comment: Wait, you're saying that I'm iterating over letters and not words???? Which means that every time I get a hit, I'm putting the word onto the list??? OH LORDY LORDY LORD!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Python lists are not expected to be unique. They preserve the order in which things were inserted. If you want the unique set of words, use Python [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set). You can create a set by passing a list to it, as in changing your last line to

`print(set(lst))`

or you can create an empty set and then add words to it as you come across them, something like this:

```
s = set()
...
for... :
  s.update(words.split(' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the actual question is, but if you want to have something like a list that doesn't allow duplicates, the datatype you want is a set. Sets don't allow duplicates so if you try to add a string to a set that's already there it will just skip it. Try initializing sets instead of lists Just a heads up as well you can initialize blank lists like this:

```
lst = []
```